# How to merge multiple dataframes in this way?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import os

main_file = pd.read_csv('D:\\Ayush\\Data\\RELIANCE.CSV')
main_file = main_file.add_prefix('RELIANCE_')




folder = os.listdir('D:\\Ayush\\Data\\Stocks & Index EOD Data ( Yahoo Finance)')
for i in folder:

    file = pd.read_csv('D:\\Ayush\\Data\\Stocks & Index EOD Data ( Yahoo Finance)\\'+i)
    file = file.add_prefix(i+'_')
    main = main_file[['RELIANCE_Date','RELIANCE_Close']].merge(file[[i+'_Date',i+'_Close']],left_on='RELIANCE_Date',right_on=i+'_Date',how='left')
```

I have multiple dataframes which have Date, open , high , low , close.  I want to have one output file which have RELIANCE_Date ( key column), RELIANCE_Close and every stock close column.

The code above gives me this output

```
RELIANCE_Date   RELIANCE_Close  ZEEL.csv_Date   ZEEL.csv_Close
0   2016-01-01  507.68  2016-01-01  432.90
1   2016-01-04  497.65  2016-01-04  421.95
2   2016-01-05  502.58  2016-01-05  425.05
3   2016-01-06  516.10  2016-01-06  423.15
4   2016-01-07  506.63  2016-01-07  415.40
... ... ... ... ...
1046    2020-03-26  1066.20 2020-03-26  128.75
1047    2020-03-27  1065.60 2020-03-27  128.05
1048    2020-03-30  1030.45 2020-03-30  125.65
1049    2020-03-31  1113.75 2020-03-31  123.95
1050    2020-04-01  1080.45 2020-04-01  120.90
```

There are couple of issues with the above output -

1) Only last stock has merged with reliance stock. I wanted 50 stocks in this dataframe

2) I don't want date of every stock. I wanted reliance date, reliance close and only close column of every other stock

Comment: Is it a typo: your dataframe is `main_file` but you assign to a different `main` on each iteration?

Comment: main is the new dataframe. If i change main to main_file, then it gives the same output

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems here:

1. you only keep the last stock: you must carefully merge into the same dataframe
2. you have date for every stock. This is normal since the name of the `right_on` and `left_on` columns are different. A possible way is to only merge the wanted columns and use the column instead of the column name for `right_on`

Code could become:

```
main_file = pd.read_csv('D:\\Ayush\\Data\\RELIANCE.CSV')
main_file = main_file.add_prefix('RELIANCE_')

main = main_file[['RELIANCE_Date','RELIANCE_Close']]
folder = os.listdir('D:\\Ayush\\Data\\Stocks & Index EOD Data ( Yahoo Finance)')
for i in folder:

    file = pd.read_csv('D:\\Ayush\\Data\\Stocks & Index EOD Data ( Yahoo Finance)\\'+i)
    file = file.add_prefix(i+'_')
    main = main.merge(file[[i+'_Close']],left_on='RELIANCE_Date',
                      right_on=file[i+'_Date'],how='left')
```

Comment: Yes, its working. Thanks a lot. Does this mean that we have mentioned left_on and right_on, we don't put file[[i+'_Date',i+'_Close']] and only use file[[i+'_Close']]  ?